# Javascript Delete dynamically created iframe element by class?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm looking at winbox.js https://nextapps-de.github.io/winbox/ to create some windows.
I'm using the iframe feature to load some external content. When its loaded I want to remove a specific element from the loaded page.

This is the code I'm using to create the iframe and attempt to delete the element.

```
"iframe": function(){

      new WinBox("Groups", {

      url: "/localwebpage",
      class: "iframe"
    });
                    
    console.log ( document.getElementById('winbox-1').contentWindow.document )
    document.getElementById('winbox-1').contentWindow.document.getElementById('toTop');

 },
```

When this is run the iframe opens loading the correct page, however I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'document')
    at Object.iframe ((index):714)
    at HTMLDivElement.onclick ((index):314)
```

Line 714 is the console.log line.

This is the HTML, `winbox-1` is the iframe and `toTop` is the element I want to remove.

[image: HTML]

How can I do this using plain javascript ?

Thanks

Comment: Well the element 'winbox-1' is a div element which has no document object inside.

Comment: @Reporter `winbox-1` is a div with an iframe containing the document object. How do I access that and remove the `toTop` ? Thanks

Comment: I deleted my answer because I got error message `Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object`. What ever the reason is.